# Jquery multiple filter like www.tretti.se

Tags: jquery, filtering

Anyone know were to find a plugin for jquery that can help me build a filter / pageing / sorting for items like http://www.tretti.se/vitvaror/frysar/frysskap

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll really only need is a [slider](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Slider) and some decent knowledge of AJAX for the paging/filtering.

Answer (score 0):

There're some pretty standard jQuery UI-like widgets there, like the slider. But I think you'd have to build it yrself. Pretty site specific.

Answer (score 0):

Try this http://www.webegg.co.uk/jquery-multiple-filter/ ;)